# Update plotly chart in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

I'm creating a plotly chart in jupyter notebook. Because I'm testing some algorithm I want to add data after the initial `fig2.show()`. But when I update the data and call `fig2.show` again a new chart is being rendered. **How can I update the chart instead of creating a new chart?**

This should be an easy task - but it's way to hard to find for me in the documentation.

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
# Set notebook mode to work in offline
pyo.init_notebook_mode()
fig2 = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=moreX2, y=moreY2))
fig2.show()
```

Then I'm using update:

```
moreX2.append(2)
moreY2.append(5)
fig2.data[0].update({"x": moreX2, "y": moreY2})
```

The chart isn't being rerendered and I tried to call `fig.show()` again, which just creates a new chart.

Comment: When working with plotly in Jupyter, AFAIK you have to run fig.show() (or even just 'fig') to update the chart. Why not have two Jupyter cells: one with the calculation, and another one with the chart, and re-run the one with the chart when you have new data?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070800/213525) worked for me, and seems like the ideal answer to this question as well. I've voted to mark this as a duplicate.

To summarize: by wrapping the `Figure` in a `FigureWidget`, we can now do exactly what the OP wanted. Although on Colab I did have to give some extra permission by calling the following:

```
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()
```