# Plotly - updating data for a figure doesn't change original line

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, google-colaboratory

taking a hint [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716543/plotly-how-to-update-redraw-a-plotly-express-figure-with-new-data) I wrote the following code in a notebook:

```
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager() #make it work on google colab notebooks
import plotly.graph_objects as go
f = go.FigureWidget()
f.add_scatter(x=[1,2,4],y=[1,2,3],mode="lines")
display(f)
```

I then ran the following code in a new cell:

```
f.data[0].x = [1,2,4,6]
f.data[0].y = [1,2,3,4]
```

Not only does the legend mention 2 traces (even when I refresh the page and restart the kernel) after running the first cell, but I also get this:
[image]

What I expect is for the original line to be replaced by the new one, not for the new one to be added.

When looking at the figure, data for only 1 trace appears: a scatter plot with the new data from the second cell.

I don't understand what's going on and can't find an example doing what I'm trying to do.